# some problems about cubes and tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have three cubes that I have used the tikz picture to figure them. Now,

1. How can I make more prominent colors to this figure?
2. I made use of `‎\begin{tikzpicture}[t][tdplot_main_coords]‎‎` so
   as to draw the picture, the result was permissible, however the file
   has an error. Making use of
   `\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]‎‎' instead, the error is
   corrected, but the picture lookout is changed to an unsuitable one.
   How can I treat this problem?

My codes are:

1. with `[t]`

   ```
   \documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
   \usepackage{subfigure}
   \usepackage{amsfonts}
   \usepackage{newlfont}
   \usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amsfonts}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{plain}
   \usepackage{mathrsfs}
   \usepackage{makecell}
   \usepackage{enumerate}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}

   \begin{document}

    \tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{125} %perspective angles

    \begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[t][tdplot_main_coords]

    \coordinate (o) at (0,0,0);

    \draw[fill=blue!5] (0,0,2) -- (0,2,2) -- (2,2,2) -- (2,0,2) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=blue!5] (2,0,0) -- (2,0,2) -- (2,2,2) -- (2,2,0) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=blue!5] (0,2,2) -- (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,2,2) -- cycle;
   \node (A) at (0.68,0.68,1) {\Huge H};
   \draw[very thick, ->, dotted] (2,1,1) -- node[midway,above]{$\dfrac{dN}{dt}$}(3.6,1,1);

    \draw[fill=yellow!5] (4,2,2) -- (4,2,0) -- (6,2,0) -- (6,2,2) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=yellow!5] (6,0,0) -- (6,0,2) -- (6,2,2) -- (6,2,0) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=yellow!5] (6,0,2) -- (4,0,2) -- (4,2,2) -- (6,2,2) -- cycle;
   \draw[very thick, ->, dotted] (6,1,1) -- node[midway,above]{$\dfrac{dR}{dt}$}(7.6,1,1);
   \node (A) at (4.68,0.68,1) {\Huge N};

    \draw[fill=red!5] (8,2,2) -- (8,2,0) -- (10,2,0) -- (10,2,2) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=red!5] (10,0,0) -- (10,0,2) -- (10,2,2) -- (10,2,0) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=red!5] (10,0,2) -- (8,0,2) -- (8,2,2) -- (10,2,2) -- cycle;
   \node (A) at (8.68,0.68,1) {\Huge R};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{pic adel}
   \label{figfarid}
   \end{figure}

    \end{document}
   ```
2. Without [t]

   ```
   \documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
   \usepackage{subfigure}
   \usepackage{amsfonts}
   \usepackage{newlfont}
   \usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amsfonts}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{plain}
   \usepackage{mathrsfs}
   \usepackage{makecell}
   \usepackage{enumerate}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}

   \begin{document}

    \tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{125} %perspective angles

    \begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

    \coordinate (o) at (0,0,0);

    \draw[fill=blue!5] (0,0,2) -- (0,2,2) -- (2,2,2) -- (2,0,2) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=blue!5] (2,0,0) -- (2,0,2) -- (2,2,2) -- (2,2,0) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=blue!5] (0,2,2) -- (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,2,2) -- cycle;
   \node (A) at (0.68,0.68,1) {\Huge H};
   \draw[very thick, ->, dotted] (2,1,1) -- node[midway,above]{$\dfrac{dN}{dt}$}(3.6,1,1);

    \draw[fill=yellow!5] (4,2,2) -- (4,2,0) -- (6,2,0) -- (6,2,2) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=yellow!5] (6,0,0) -- (6,0,2) -- (6,2,2) -- (6,2,0) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=yellow!5] (6,0,2) -- (4,0,2) -- (4,2,2) -- (6,2,2) -- cycle;
   \draw[very thick, ->, dotted] (6,1,1) -- node[midway,above]{$\dfrac{dR}{dt}$}(7.6,1,1);
   \node (A) at (4.68,0.68,1) {\Huge N};

    \draw[fill=red!5] (8,2,2) -- (8,2,0) -- (10,2,0) -- (10,2,2) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=red!5] (10,0,0) -- (10,0,2) -- (10,2,2) -- (10,2,0) -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=red!5] (10,0,2) -- (8,0,2) -- (8,2,2) -- (10,2,2) -- cycle;
   \node (A) at (8.68,0.68,1) {\Huge R};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{pic adel}
   \label{figfarid}
   \end{figure}

    \end{document}
   ```

Comment: What did you expect the `t` to do?

Comment: Someone introduced this command to me.

Comment: Yes, but what did you want it to do? It's something that typically is seen with e.g. `tabular` and `minipage`, but unless that person had defined a TikZ style called `t`, it isn't used with `tikzpicture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expected the `t` option to do,but to change the view of the graphic, play with the numbers in

```
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{125}
```

As for the colors, those are specified in the `\draw` commands, e.g. `fill=blue!5`. The syntax `<color>!N` means that the color is mixed with white (I think), `N`% of the specified color, the rest white. So in `blue!5` you get 5% blue, 95% white.

Exactly what you mean by prominent, I don't know, but you could for example increase the percentage for blue, yellow and red.
An example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{155} %perspective angles

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

 \coordinate (o) at (0,0,0);

\draw[fill=blue!25] (0,0,2) -- (0,2,2) -- (2,2,2) -- (2,0,2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!25] (2,0,0) -- (2,0,2) -- (2,2,2) -- (2,2,0) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!25] (0,2,2) -- (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,2,2) -- cycle;
\node (A) at (0.68,0.68,1) {\Huge H};
\draw[very thick, ->, dotted] (2,1,1) -- node[midway,above]{$\dfrac{dN}{dt}$}(3.6,1,1);

\draw[fill=yellow!25] (4,2,2) -- (4,2,0) -- (6,2,0) -- (6,2,2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=yellow!25] (6,0,0) -- (6,0,2) -- (6,2,2) -- (6,2,0) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=yellow!25] (6,0,2) -- (4,0,2) -- (4,2,2) -- (6,2,2) -- cycle;
\draw[very thick, ->, dotted] (6,1,1) -- node[midway,above]{$\dfrac{dR}{dt}$}(7.6,1,1);
\node (A) at (4.68,0.68,1) {\Huge N};

\draw[fill=red!25] (8,2,2) -- (8,2,0) -- (10,2,0) -- (10,2,2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=red!25] (10,0,0) -- (10,0,2) -- (10,2,2) -- (10,2,0) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=red!25] (10,0,2) -- (8,0,2) -- (8,2,2) -- (10,2,2) -- cycle;
\node (A) at (8.68,0.68,1) {\Huge R};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{pic adel}
\label{figfarid}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```